# Why there is discrepanceis in number of instance methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-1.9.3

While going through the [ruby monk](https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/37-classes-inheritance/lessons/83-understanding-inheritance) I have seen the count of Float instance methods as 201 but when I tried in my irb it is showing just 114. It will be really helpful if someone make me understand why there is change in the number of count in instance methods and on what factors this instance methods depends on.

```
puts Float.instance_methods.count
```

Comment: Sure it's not a difference in the versions of ruby being used?

Comment: Hmm.. probably not. I get 112 in ruby 1.9, and 114 in ruby 2.2. Not sure where 201 could be coming from.

Comment: I am using ruby 2.2.0, 1.9.3 and have found difference in both the version, but from where this 201 came ?

Comment: Where did you get 201? I don't see it at the Ruby Monk link. Note in v2.2, `1.0.methods.count #=> 114`, but also  
`1.0.private_methods.count #=> 76`. `114+76 => 190`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I have already given link for page where the result is 201.  please scroll down in the page and you will find it

Comment: I see, I have to run some code to see it.

Comment: @CarySwoveland  For you sir: https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/37-classes-inheritance/lessons/83-understanding-inheritance

Comment: I tweeted @jasim_ab who is the owner of that material. waiting for his reply as well

Comment: I have tried to explain, hope you get it. :)

Comment: @SharvyAhmed Thanks a lot, really appreciate your effort

Answer (score 2):

There is no discrepancy in total number of instance methods of Ruby `Float` class (of same version). The number may vary based on Ruby version, but no two same Ruby versions will have different instance methods.

> I have seen the count of Float instance methods as 201

What you are seeing is the total number of instance methods of Extended Float class. The extension is done by Rails.

For example, in Rubymonk terminal, instance methods list of Float class shows `duplicable?` in their list, which is obviously is not an instance method of Float class. It's implemented in `ActiveSupport` by extending the core `Object` class and is deprecated after Rails 3.2.13.

Comment: You are saying that the number is higher than what one would expect because Rails (or some parts thereof) had been loaded. That's a convincing explanation, but I would not go so far as saying "there is no discrepancy".  After all, this course is called "Ruby Primer", a course in pure Ruby.  It's reasonable to expect that the numbers of instance methods shown as being defined on Float would be for just Ruby, and that number does not vary greatly from one recent version to the next. cyborg, I suggest you pass that suggestion on to one of the course authors.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, Different Ruby versions may have a little difference between instance methods but not like 100. And I have checked instance methods of Float class in Rubymonk console, they showed all instance methods of Object class (Extended by ActiveSupport Core) along with instance methods of Float class (Defined in Ruby Core).

Comment: Yep, if you do 'puts ActiveSupport.to_s' in the RubyMonk console, it is indeed defined. Silly - it probably shouldn't be there.

Comment: We have first-hand evidence  in the form of the OP's question that saying `Float` has 201 instance methods is baffling to students who wish to check the calculations on their own computers.  Egad, it's baffling to many of us with a fair bit of experience. Should we expect newbies to conclude the difference is due to the fact that Rails is loaded, when the only rails they know about are made of steel? No, the course should display the number of instance methods defined on Float for (some recent version of) pure-Ruby. That's not difficult and to me it's a "no-brainer".

Comment: @CarySwoveland, you are absolutely right, for a newbie it would be really hard and confusing. They should have exposed the Ruby console instead of Rails console.

Comment: btw, I upvoted you answer even though I disagree with the "no discrepancy" assertion...

Comment: I appreciate your appreciation. :) You can edit my answer, if the answer sounds slightly incorrect or improper.

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland and SharvyAhmed. I got what I want from this question. My doubt got cleared though I am trying to connect with author of that material as well. Let my learning grow and interest in ruby rise exponentially :)